# Cross compiling portAudio for Intel Edison

Tags: linux, linker, cross-compiling, portaudio, intel-edison

I am using the cross compile environemt from the [Intel Site](https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/edison/downloads) and have successfully compiled several other libraries using it (libsndfile, alsa, fftw) but when I try to compile portaudio it refuses to link to the proper directories. Here is the error I get:

```
if test -n " bindings/cpp" ; then for dir in " bindings/cpp"; do make -C $dir all; done ; fi
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/theslat/Downloads/portaudio/bindings/cpp'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/theslat/Downloads/portaudio/bindings/cpp/lib'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link i586-poky-linux-g++  -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=/usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -version-info 0:12:0 -no-undefined -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o libportaudiocpp.la -rpath /usr/local/lib BlockingStream.lo CallbackInterface.lo CallbackStream.lo CFunCallbackStream.lo CppFunCallbackStream.lo Device.lo DirectionSpecificStreamParameters.lo Exception.lo HostApi.lo InterfaceCallbackStream.lo MemFunCallbackStream.lo Stream.lo StreamParameters.lo System.lo SystemDeviceIterator.lo SystemHostApiIterator.lo ../../../lib/libportaudio.la 
libtool: link: i586-poky-linux-g++  -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=/usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/lib/crti.o /usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux/4.9.1/crtbeginS.o  .libs/BlockingStream.o .libs/CallbackInterface.o .libs/CallbackStream.o .libs/CFunCallbackStream.o .libs/CppFunCallbackStream.o .libs/Device.o .libs/DirectionSpecificStreamParameters.o .libs/Exception.o .libs/HostApi.o .libs/InterfaceCallbackStream.o .libs/MemFunCallbackStream.o .libs/Stream.o .libs/StreamParameters.o .libs/System.o .libs/SystemDeviceIterator.o .libs/SystemHostApiIterator.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/theslat/Downloads/portaudio/lib/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib ../../../lib/.libs/libportaudio.so -L/usr/edison/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux/../../lib/i586-poky-linux/gcc/i586-poky-linux/4.9.1 -L/usr/edison/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux/../../lib/i586-poky-linux/gcc -L/usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/lib -L/usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux/4.9.1 -L/usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/lib /usr/lib/libstdc++.so -lm -lc -lgcc_s /usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/lib/i586-poky-linux/4.9.1/crtendS.o /usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux/usr/lib/crtn.o  -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign --sysroot=/usr/edison/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux -O2 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed   -Wl,-soname -Wl,libportaudiocpp.so.0 -o .libs/libportaudiocpp.so.0.0.12
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:311: libportaudiocpp.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/theslat/Downloads/portaudio/bindings/cpp/lib'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:333: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/theslat/Downloads/portaudio/bindings/cpp'
make: *** [Makefile:251: all-recursive] Error 2
```

It seems like it is trying to link against my computers normal libstdc++ and I don't know why. I have tried feedin `configure` a variaty of LDFLAG with the right directories and have reinstalled the toolchain and all my multilibs but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also ran into this issue and the easiest way is to source the environment file again after doing a sudo su on the same command line and then do a make install.

Here are the steps I followed to cross compile portaudio for intel edison:

1. Download the cross compiler edison-toolchain-20150120-linux64.tar.bz2 and the script toolchain-20140724-linux64.sh from this [link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24472/Cross-Compiler-Toolchain-for-Intel-Edison-Maker-Board)
2. Extract the toolchain, run the script (you can put it in your home directory somewhere if you wish) and set up the cross-compile environment

> ```
> $ tar -xvf edison-toolchain-20150120-linux64.tar.bz2   
> $ chmod +x toolchain-20140724-linux64.sh   
> $ ./toolchain-20140724-linux64.sh  
> $ source /opt/poky-edison/1.6/environment-setup-core2-32-poky-linux
> ```

3. Check the environment on your shell:

> ```
> $ echo $CC  
> $ i586-poky-linux-gcc -m32 -march=core2 -mtune=core2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -mstackrealign -fno-omit-frame-pointer --sysroot=/opt/poky-edison/1.6/sysroots/core2-32-poky-linux
> ```

Configure, compile and install portaudio:

> ```
> $ ./configure
> $ make
> $ sudo su
> # source /opt/poky-edison/1.6/environment-setup-core2-32-poky-linux
> # make install
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am suprised that nobody grabbed this but also that it was difficult to find the proper answer anywhere else despite seeing many other people with similar (unresolved issues). The answer is frankly so simple I am embarrased that I overlooked it, but here it is so maybe someone else can find it.

`make install` required root privilages if the cross-compile SDK is in `/opt` or somewhere else you do not own. But... sudo does not preserve the environmental variable I had set up for the toolchain! Very simple, also `su -m` does not work the way I thought it did. Working solutions as follows:

1. Just install the SDK somewhere in your home directory. you now have write permissions, problem solved.
2. Run a single command as root while preserving the environment: `su -m <yourUserName> -c '$CC main.cpp -lfoo -lbar ...'`

The key in numer 2 is the username after `-m`, at least on my system leaving out the username there produced no errors but failed to preserve my environment.